# Joining three different tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I am trying to get the count value of two tables and use the member id as key to count the rows of the other tables, I have this code so far but it is outputting a big value for comCount and empty value for chatCount. Here is my code

```
SELECT members.*
, comments.commenter_id
, cb.user_id
, COUNT(comments.comment) AS comCount
, COUNT(cb.message) AS chatCount
FROM members 
INNER JOIN comments ON members.id = comments.commenter_id
INNER JOIN chat_box AS cb ON members.id = cb.user_id
WHERE members.id ='$profileId'`
```

Comment: I am sure, before I added the chat_box join it displays the comment count without a problem

Comment: can you givre sample records with desired result?

Comment: Here is the fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/87637/5/0

Comment: the fiddle produces correct result. what is the problem?

Comment: that is a query with one join, I get a really big number when i use both joins as used in my questions, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59505/1

Comment: here is my the result of my deleted answer, will I undelete it? http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59505/3

Comment: compare our result, http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/59505/4

Comment: yes put your answer back :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT  members.* , 
        a.commenter_id , 
        b.user_id , 
        a.totalComment , 
        b.totalChat
FROM    members 
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT commenter_id, COUNT(*) totalComment
            FROM comments
            GROUP BY commenter_id
        ) a ON members.id = a.commenter_id
        INNER JOIN 
        (
            SELECT user_id, COUNT(*) totalChat
            FROM chat_box 
            GROUP BY user_id            
        ) b  ON members.id = b.user_id
WHERE   members.id = '$profileId'
```

As a sidenote, the query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` if the value(*s*) came from the outside. Please take a look at the article below to learn how to prevent from it. By using PreparedStatements you can get rid of using single quotes around values.

- [How to *prevent SQL injection* in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Thanks JW, it seems there was an extra ' at the end  I did not realize till now ^_^

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT members.*
, comments.commenter_id
, cb.user_id
,(select  COUNT(1) from comments where commenter_id = members.id) AS comCount
,(select count(1) from chat_box where user_id = members.id) AS chatCount
FROM members 
WHERE members.id ='$profileId'`
```